# How can one test C\C++ code which uses MPI calls: is there any set of mock functions, that I can use?

Tags: c++, c, testing, mocking, mpi

```
#include <mpi.h>
double f() {
    double timer = MPI_Wtime();
    return timer;
}
```

What I am searching for is some set of mock MPI functions, so I can `#include <mpi_mocks.h>` instead of mpi.h and get it compiled without linking to MPI library. It could also be something like `#define MOCK` which will trigger this behavior in mpi.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there are no mocks you could just #include and be done. However, it should be no big deal to write the needed functions yourself and for whichever mocking framework you chose to use. Just start with an empty header and look which functions you compiler complains about.

Comment: What do you mean "#inlcude and be done"? Than I must link it with a library, that has the implementation of MPI_Wtime and that is something I am trying to avoid (as mentioned in the question). Do I miss something?

Comment: I agree it is not a big deal at least for MPI_Wtime, but then I might need something else, and then something else, and then you have yet another reinvented wheel.

Comment: With "#include and be done" I mean that that there is no `mpi_mocks.h` out there that is a header-only mocking library for mpi. At least I doubt that there is one, amon other things because normally you want to have such mocks in the style of the mocking framework you use, and those have different APIs (e.g. google mocks, turtle mocks etc.). To do such a thing yourself I could imagine to first #include an empty mpi_mocks.h, run the compiler, gather all its complaints about unknown MPI_something functions and use some scripting language to generate the mpi_mocks.h with all needed functions.

Comment: Thanks, now I see, what you meant (I have read your answer once more and realized, that I have misinterpreted it. Mea culpa.) Currently I do it the way you describe. I do not mind linking with some mpi_mock.lib if there would be one.

Comment: Well, I don't think there will be a `mpi_mock.lib` either, if it's not provided with `mpi.lib`. But if `mpi.h` contains just the function prototypes you could of course just use that to generate *all* function bodies and whatever mocking functionality you want. Compile that into some `mpi_mock.lib` and link it instead of the real MPI lib in your test projects. That way you even don't have to resort to conditional includes in your application sources, and it's a one-time effort because you mock away any MPI function call that could be dreamt of.

Comment: Just had a look around, maybe this is something you could use: http://atomicobject.com/pages/Moxy+Code+Generator I did not have a deeper look into it, bit it seems to create mocks automatically.

Comment: I started such a thing [here](http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~ljdursi/code/mpinull.tgz) years ago when getting MPI up and running on one's laptop was tedious; it was aimed at Fortran, though, and only has the routines I needed at the time (no Wtime, as it turns out) but might be a decent starting point.  I abandoned the effort when it became clear that it was much easier just to link to the MPI library even for single-processor runs.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan and Arne for your ideas and attention. I started this thread because I do not know how to use MPI functions in the context of the unit testing framework (gtest). Although as I discuss it here with you it feels like I realize the essence of my problem and there might be a completely different way to tackle it (googling mpi gtest does give me some results).